# SVG mouse pointer location

Tags: javascript, pointers, svg, location, mouseevent

I would like to know how I can use JavaScript to find out the location of the mouse pointer when it is within the bounds of an SVG viewBox. Do I need to use the event model to keep track of all the various mouse motion events, or is there a way I can poll the mouse pointer to have it tell me where it is when I need it?

Comment: Wow. Someone's actually using SVG for the kind of complex stuff it was intended? There is hope!

Comment: Developing in SVG is great. It's the limited options for deploying my app that drags it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook to the `onmousemove` event and access the event object:

```
function on_mouse_move(evt) {
  var
    x = evt.clientX,
    y = evt.clientY;
}
```

(This assumes `on_mouse_move` is connected to the `onmousemove` event of your SVG document).